# enable and disable logo in hamburger menu android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, hamburger-menu

Actual scenario.

I have an drawer menu with some menu options. Each menu click replace the fragment of the activity in which i want to show the logo with hamburger menu in home page fragment only and in rest of other pages  i want hide it.

i tried like below

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setLogo(null);
```

to in rest of the fragments onResume() method

But in result menu logo gone when it call **setLogo(null);** but it was not come to previous state on home page even after setting **setLogo(R.drawable.logo)**

Advance thanks for helping..

Comment: try the accepted answer from   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498534/hide-menuitem-in-some-fragments on every other fragment

Answer (score 0):

To disable just call:

```
yourDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```